# Silverlight - rebinding to a property?

Tags: silverlight, binding, dependency-properties

I'm just getting started with silverlight.
Basically I have a silverlight user control that has various dataGrids and a combobox, their item sources set to the properties of a custom plain c# object.
My problem is that I have a dropdown list that when a user selects an item from the list a new row should appear in one of the grids.
All I'm doing is handling the SelectionChanged event and adding a new item to to a list in my custom object and setting the itemsource for the grid again. This doesnt seem to work; no row is added to the dataGrid
I have no idea how to force my grid to "rebind" to this property.
I've been reading about dependency properties, are these what I need?

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list you are binding against should be of the type ObservableCollection. Then the datagrid should display the new item automatically .

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you assign the same List to the `ItemsSource` the `DataGrid` knows its the same List so it does nothing.

As Henrik points out you should expose an `Observable<T>` not a `List<T>` for properties that are to be bound to `ItemsSource` properties of multi-item controls such as `DataGrid`, `ListBox` etc.

In addition your "plain c# objects" should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface if you want changes made by code to these properties to automatically appear in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is update the binding source - which is relatively easily done.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGrid.GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSource).UpdateSource();
}
```

This is a tad hack-y but will do what you need it to do. Implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) is another great suggestion.

Silverlight show have some great info on `INotifyPropertyChanged` [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/How-to-implement-INotifyPropertyChanged-interface.aspx)